# Square gaps and overlapping grid infill artillery sidewinder x1

Tags: build-plate, infill, mechanics, print-axis-offset, artillery-sidewinder-x1

I'm trying to print something that's very wide and flat, like a board that covers the entire build plate (300x300) but is only 15 layers high. I've chosen grid infill and it works at the front left corner of the printer, but at the back right corner, some of the infill lines get all squashed together and overlap.

At first I thought it was skipping infill lines, but I realized those same lines that are smashed at the top right corner even out at the bottom left and print as expected. It's as if the angle isn't quite right in the G-code and as the nozzle progresses along the plate it gets just a fraction of a degree off, which makes an exacerbated effect when the line it needs to print is so long. But why only on those parts of the print? The printer seems to think that one line is right next to the other line, when in reality there's almost a 1 cm gap!

How do I eliminate those square gaps and make the gridlines straight?

I'm on an Artillery Sidewinder x1.

[image: Layers overlapping]

Comment: A remarkable observation is that the grid infill lines on the right (of where some of the gridlines taper) are parallel to the to the left of the tapered infill lines. I doubt this to be a slicer issue, but maybe you could share the G-code file for us to take a look? It is hard to imagine the issue is related to hardware missing steppes as a result of some kind of obstruction as the grid line recover to the correct pattern, this really got my head spinning.

Comment: I think I may have found part of the problem. I had been messing with the settings in my slicer to let me print using the _entire_ bed and I had accidentally shifted the model and it allowed it to be sliced which told the printer to print too far off to the right of the bed. The machine had to interpret how to print locations that its hardware wasn't capable of and this was what it decided to do.

Comment: Please make it a (partial) answer!

Answer (score 2):

I think I may have found part of the problem. I had been messing with the settings in my slicer to let me print using the entire bed and I had accidentally shifted the model and it allowed it to be sliced which told the printer to print too far off to the right of the bed. The machine had to interpret how to print locations that its hardware wasn't capable of and this was what it decided to do.